# npm ERR! could not determine executable to run ---Error de React Native

Tags: nodejs, react-native, npm

He estado programando en *React Native* desde hace unos días y hoy de la nada me aparece este error que no me permite ejecutar ningún proyecto, ni siquiera el que crea el mismo *React Native* por default, el error es el siguiente:

> npm ERR! could not determine executable to run